# the actual writes only after the transaction enters the committed state

Tags: transaction, database-theory

The text below is from Database System Concepts by Silberschatz. It says that the actual writes take place only after the transaction enters the committed state.

**My question**: When the transaction has entered the committed state, there's no more statement to be executed, so who will perform these actual writes?

> We must be cautious when dealing with observable external writes, such as writes
> to a user’s screen, or sending email. Once such a write has occurred, it cannot be
> erased, since it may have been seen external to the database system. Most systems
> allow such writes to take place only after the transaction has entered the committed
> state. One way to implement such a scheme is for the database system to store any value
> associated with such external writes temporarily in a special relation in the database,
> and to perform the actual writes only after the transaction enters the committed state. If
> the system should fail after the transaction has entered the committed state, but before
> it could complete the external writes, the database system will carry out the external
> writes (using the data in non-volatile storage) when the system is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, "writes" in the current context is referring to external writes (such as writes to a user’s screen, or sending email).

So a banking application, for instance, first stores deposit information in the database, then commits the database transaction, and only then does an "external write" - showing confirmation on a terminal screen or sending a confirmation email. - https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2232